# Prove that set is closed in $L_{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

Consider $L_{2} = (x_{1}\dots x_{n}\dots)$, where $x_{i} \ge 0$ and $\sqrt{\sum x_{i}^{2}} < +\infty$. Consider subspace $Cl_{2} = (x_{1}\dots x_{n}\dots)$ , where $0 \le x_{n} \le \frac{1}{2^{n}}$. Prove that this subspace is closed and prove Int$(Cl_{2}) = \varnothing$.

I guess first one is because Bd$(Cl_{2}) \subset Cl_{2}$. So the set is closed.

And for second : because there is infinity many $x_{n}$, so there is no $\epsilon >0$ and $a \in Cl_{2} : B_{\epsilon}(a) \subset Cl_{2}$ (except of $0 \in Cl_{2}$, but $0$ is bound of our set.)

Am I right?

Comment: What is the boudary of $Cl_2$?

Comment: @amsmath $(0\dots0\dots)$ and $(1,1/2,1/4\dots)$

Comment: @openspace Why would that be the boundary? Finding the boundary amounts to finding the closure and removing the interior, so presumably you should be able to do these things before understanding the boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the family of subsets $$\operatorname{Cl}_2^n = \{\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\in \ell^2 : 0\leq x_n\leq 2^{-n}\}$$ First, we can see that $\operatorname{Cl}_2^n$ is closed for each $n$, as it is the preimage of $[0, 2^{-n}]$ under the continuous map $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\mapsto x_n$ from $\ell^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then, as $$\operatorname{Cl}_2 = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \operatorname{Cl}_2^n$$ and the arbitrary intersection of closed subsets is closed, $\operatorname{Cl}_2$ is closed. Furthermore, as $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k = 0$ for any sequence $\{x_k\}\in \ell^2$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can construct a sequence $\{y_k\}$ by choosing an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n < \epsilon$ and letting $y_k = x_k$ for all $k\neq n$ and $y_n = x_n-\epsilon < 0$. Therefore, as for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a $\{y_k\}\notin \operatorname{Cl}_2$ such that $\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lvert x_k-y_k\rvert^2} = \epsilon$, we have that $\{x_k\}\in \overline{\operatorname{Cl}_2^c}$, so $\{x_k\}\in \partial\operatorname{Cl}_2 := \overline{\operatorname{Cl}_2}\cap \overline{\operatorname{Cl}_2^c}$. Therefore, $\operatorname{Cl}_2^{\circ} := \operatorname{Cl}_2\setminus \partial\operatorname{Cl}_2 = \emptyset$.

Comment: But I guess $y_{n}=\epsilon-x_{n}$?

Comment: And what is $Cl_{2}^{c}$?

Comment: No, $y_n = x_n-\epsilon$, as $x_n < \epsilon$, so we want $y_n < 0$. Generally, for a set $S$, $S^c$ is the notation we use for the complement of $S$.

Comment: why we have the last equation?

Comment: The one with $\operatorname{Cl}_2^{\circ}$? Because we've shown that any element of $\operatorname{Cl}_2$ is also in $\partial\operatorname{Cl}_2$.